# Redirect stdout and stderr in real time

Tags: ruby, terminal, command-line-interface, freebsd, csh

I think that's an easy question but couldn't find the solution. I redirect the stdout and stderr of ruby script doing 'puts' and sometimes errors (!) to a log file like this :

```
bundle exec rake import:long_task --trace  >& log/import.log &
```

But it doen't seem to flush the `puts` in realtime to the file and when its get an exception it puts the traceback in the top `import.log`. So, that's not perfect to debug but it works.

How I can redirect the output of a script in realtime to a file to see exactly what I would have seen if I have launch it directly in the terminal without redirecting ?

Using: Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3.2, FreeBSD and csh shell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`STDOUT.sync = true` if you don't want to `flush` every time

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but have you considered using:

```
$stdout.puts "something on /dev/stdout"
$stdout.flush
$stderr.puts "something on /dev/stderr"
$stderr.flush
```

See the [IO#flush documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-i-flush) for details.

Comment: my mistake, I was thinking it was csh related. But why it flushs automatically the output when we use puts in terminal?